# Overflow on each side

Tags: html, css

I want to zoom the picture on hover.
So, it works so far but the end result isn't what I want.
When the picture zooms, it stops on the left side of the containing `div` and enlarges to the right side.

I already found the `direction` property but with that I can only switch the side behaviors. Something like `direction: all` would propably work, but it doesn't exist.

What I expect:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z2Ad/)

I recommend pure CSS without any JavaScript and jQuery code.

Comment: If you don't care about IE 6, 7, 8, then why not use translate instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#container img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*transition: all 0.5s ease;*/
}
#container img:hover {
    left: -5%;
    width: 110%;
    height: 110%;
}
```

Add `left: -5%` to you CSS rule for `img:hover`.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Em7yu/

Comment: came to same conclusion +1 (simple and effective.)